# The flexdashboard reactive global profile parameters problem

Tags: r, shiny, scoping, flexdashboard, shiny-reactivity

I've been trying to come up with a solution for what seems like a common use case related to this [discussion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-practices-for-global-external-variables-used-in-a-module/5820/11) for a couple of weeks now with no luck. This conversation comes the closest to explaining how global variables might be created and used across Shiny apps - but I'm having difficulty understanding the nuances of the code provided.
This SO post is similar but not quite what I'm confused about:

- [Pass reactives to flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653627/pass-reactives-to-flexdashboard)

#### The Global Profile Problem

We have an app that walks a user through a "wizard setup"
 intro that allows them to configure certain parameters that impact the functioning of individual Shiny application modules in a multiple app flexdashboard. These need to be stored globally, passed into the sub applications, and in the "profile" app need to be modifiable *at the global level* such that changes made to the global profile modify the functioning of the other modules accordingly.

I'm attempting to make sense of the code provided in this post and adapt it to this use case but thus far I've been unable to determine how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

````
---
title: "Global Profile Reprex"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

Global <- function(input, output, session) {
  profile  <- reactiveValues(goal = 5)
  return(profile)
}
Module1 <- function(input, output, session, globals) {
  goal = globals$profile
}

```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Access
```{r 'Access'}
# This is just intented to access the global reactive values
ui <- renderUI(fluidPage(
    shiny::htmlOutput("viewProfile")
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  globalProfile <- callModule(Global, "global")
    output$viewProfile <- shiny::renderText({
        paste0("Goal:",globalProfile$profile$goal)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Update
```{r 'Update'}
# This is intended to allow a user to update the global reactive values.
ui <- renderUI(fluidPage(

    fluidRow(width = 12,
             column(12,
                    textInput(inputId = "goal",
                              label = "Goals (time per week)",
                              placeholder = "ex 4h42m 4:42"))),
    fluidRow(width = 12,
             column(5), column(2, submitButton("Save Changes", icon("save", lib = "font-awesome"))), 
column(5)) , 
    shiny::htmlOutput("test.text")
))



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  globalProfile <- callModule(Global, "global")

    reactive({
        print("profile Saved")
      mod1 <- callModule(Module1, "mod1", globalProfile)
        mod1$profile$goal <- input$goal
    })
    output$test.text <- shiny::renderText({
        c("Goal",globalProfile$profile$goal) %>% paste0(collapse = " ")

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```


R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5         shiny_1.4.0.9000     RevoUtils_11.0.3    
[4] RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3.1             pillar_1.4.2            
 [3] compiler_3.5.3           later_1.0.0             
 [5] plyr_1.8.4               tools_3.5.3             
 [7] digest_0.6.22.3          packrat_0.4.9-3         
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4.9000     jsonlite_1.6.9000       
[11] evaluate_0.14            tibble_2.1.3            
[13] gtable_0.2.0             pkgconfig_2.0.3         
[15] rlang_0.4.1              rstudioapi_0.10.0-9000  
[17] yaml_2.2.0               xfun_0.11.1             
[19] fastmap_1.0.1            withr_2.1.2             
[21] dplyr_0.8.3              httr_1.4.1.9000         
[23] knitr_1.26               grid_3.5.3              
[25] tidyselect_0.2.5         flexdashboard_0.5.1.9000
[27] glue_1.3.1.9000          R6_2.4.1                
[29] rmarkdown_1.17           ggplot2_3.1.0           
[31] purrr_0.3.3.9000         promises_1.1.0.9000     
[33] scales_1.0.0.9000        htmltools_0.4.0.9000    
[35] rsconnect_0.8.13         assertthat_0.2.1        
[37] xtable_1.8-4             mime_0.7                
[39] colorspace_1.4-0         httpuv_1.5.2.9000       
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1           munsell_0.5.0           
[43] crayon_1.3.4
````

Update

The access function works with this simplified code, but I am still unable to figure out how to update the global reactiveValues from inside the Update app.

````
---
title: "Global Profile Reprex"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)


  profile  <- reactiveValues(goal = 5)

Module1 <- function(input, output, session, globals) {
  goal = globals$profile
}

```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Access
```{r 'Access'}
# This is just intented to access the global reactive values
ui <- renderUI(fluidPage(
    shiny::htmlOutput("viewProfile")
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$viewProfile <- shiny::renderText({
        paste0("Goal:", profile$goal)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Update

```{r 'Update'}
# This is intended to allow a user to update the global reactive values.
ui <- renderUI(fluidPage(

    fluidRow(width = 12,
             column(12,
                    textInput(inputId = "goal",
                              label = "Goals (time per week)",
                              placeholder = "ex 4h42m 4:42"))),
    fluidRow(width = 12,
             column(5), column(2, submitButton("Save Changes", icon("save", lib = "font-awesome"))), 
column(5)) , 
    shiny::htmlOutput("test.text")
))



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    reactive({
        print("profile Saved")
      profile$goal <<- input$goal
    })
    output$test.text <- shiny::renderText({
        c("Goal: ",profile$goal) %>% paste0(collapse = " ")

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Alright, solved this after some tinkering! Use of `observeEvent` and the save `actionButton` correctly updates the reactive profile values.

````
---
title: "Global Profile Reprex"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)


  profile  <- reactiveValues(goal = 5)

Module1 <- function(input, output, session, globals) {
  goal = globals$profile
}

```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Access
```{r 'Access'}
# This is just intented to access the global reactive values
ui <- renderUI(fluidPage(
    shiny::htmlOutput("viewProfile")
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$viewProfile <- shiny::renderText({
        paste0("Goal:", profile$goal)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Column {data-width=500} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Update
```{r 'Update'}
# This is intended to allow a user to update the global reactive values.
profile  <- reactiveValues(goal = 5)
uiUpdate <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(width = 12,
             column(12,
                    textInput(inputId = "goal",
                              label = "Goals (time per week)",
                              placeholder = "ex 4h42m 4:42")), actionButton("save","Save Changes", icon("save", lib = "font-awesome"))), 
  shiny::htmlOutput("test.text")
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
serverUpdate <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$save,{
       # print("profile Saved")
      message("Profile Saved")
      profile$goal <<-  input$goal
    })
    output$test.text <- shiny::renderText({
        c("Goal: ",profile$goal) %>% paste0(collapse = " ")

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = uiUpdate, server = serverUpdate)
```
````